# Combining multiple numpy arrays into one

Tags: python, numpy

I have this O/P as shown in the below pic

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y19t4.png]

My O/P consists of around 100+ numpy arrays like the one shown above. I'm trying to combine all these 100+ numpy arrays into an single numpy array for further data processing. Any ideas on how to get this done???? I'm using python V3.4

Comment: What does O/P stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hstack` and `vstack`:

```
In [29]: hstack((arange(10) for _ in range(10)))
Out[29]:
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2,
   3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
   6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
   9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1,
   2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [30]: vstack((arange(10) for _ in range(10)))
Out[30]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```